# I want to synchronize the configuration file from container to the host,Where did I go wrong?what should i do?

Tags: docker, trino

i run :

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --name trino11  -v /data/dir1:/usr/lib/trino/etc  trinodb/trino
```

show:

```
root@yy:/data# docker run -p 8380:8080 --name trino000  -v /data/dir1:/usr/lib/trino/etc  trinodb/trino
+ [[ ! -d /usr/lib/trino/etc ]]
+ set +e
+ grep -s -q node.id /usr/lib/trino/etc/node.properties
+ NODE_ID_EXISTS=2
+ set -e
+ NODE_ID=
+ [[ 2 != 0 ]]
+ NODE_ID=-Dnode.id=374f76e5daef
+ exec /usr/lib/trino/bin/launcher run -Dnode.id=374f76e5daef
ERROR: Config file is missing: /usr/lib/trino/etc/config.properties
```

if not need auto copy config file from container to host machine,i can run

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --name trino trinodb/trino
```

from https://hub.docker.com/r/trinodb/trino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Trino configuration should be mounted at `/etc/trino`

```
-v /your/path:/etc/trino
```

Binding to `/usr/lib/trino/etc` can confuse the launcher script.

See https://github.com/trinodb/trino/blob/master/core/docker/README.md for more information.

Comment: ```(base) root@DESKTOP-9TU3VS1:~# docker run -p 8080:8080 -it --name trino  -v /data/dir1:/etc/trino  trinodb/trino
+ [[ ! -d /usr/lib/trino/etc ]]
+ [[ -d /etc/trino ]]
+ ln -s /etc/trino /usr/lib/trino/etc
+ set +e
+ grep -s -q node.id /usr/lib/trino/etc/node.properties
+ NODE_ID_EXISTS=2
+ set -e
+ NODE_ID=
+ [[ 2 != 0 ]]
+ NODE_ID=-Dnode.id=7f2923bc8578
+ exec /usr/lib/trino/bin/launcher run -Dnode.id=7f2923bc8578
ERROR: Config file is missing: /etc/trino/config.properties```

Comment: @chinayangyongyong it may be easier to talk this on `#troubleshooting` on [Trino community slack](https://trino.io/slack.html)